# heading not extending to the end of the div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a heading banner that overlays across a background image for a tile. To make it responsive, I set the width to auto and it looks great on a collapsed screen (see capture below). Also, I'm using Bootstrap 4.

[image]

However, on full screen resolution, the heading background doesn't extend to the end of the div. I've tried to eliminate any padding, but I can't seem to get it to go to the end. See image.[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<!--browse by category section-->
    <section id="category">
        <div class="card-header text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">Browse Workouts by Category</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row btn-warning">
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary" id="cardio">
                <h1 class="text-center">Cardio</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
                Hi
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
                Hi
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
                Hi
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
                Hi
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
                Hi
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and my CSS:

```
/*--------------*/
/*---CATEGORIES-----*/
/*--------------*/

#cardio {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url('../img/users/pexels-photo-460520.jpeg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
}

#cardio h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(93,139,229,0.7), rgba(93,139,229,0.7));
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 .row, .col {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#cardio {
   padding: 0;
}

#cardio h1 {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Keep the rest as is

Comment: @J.G.Sable pay attention you are modifying the style of bootstrap classes ! which is not good ! and no need to use width:100% with block element

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing the `container` div before the `row`. then, to force the title to be full width you need to add negative margin in order to override the padding of the outer class `col-sm-2`.

*Avoid changing styles of bootstrap classes as I saw in other answers, this can break some of your other layout.*

```css
/*--------------*/


/*---CATEGORIES-----*/


/*--------------*/

#cardio {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('../img/users/pexels-photo-460520.jpeg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

#cardio h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-right:-15px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(93, 139, 229, 0.7), rgba(93, 139, 229, 0.7));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--browse by category section-->
<section id="category">
  <div class="card-header text-center">
    <h4 class="card-title">Browse Workouts by Category</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row btn-warning">
      <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary" id="cardio">
        <h1 class="text-center">Cardio</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
        Hi
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
        Hi
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
        Hi
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
        Hi
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
        Hi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```